# How to skip a specific gradle task

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I want to skip one of the tasks of Android gradle build, so I tried something like

```
project.tasks.getByName("transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug").onlyIf {
    println("Skipping")
    return false
}
```

However, the task is not found, even though I can see it in the tasks that are executed...
Any idea how can I get this task? I guess it should be dependant of one of the tasks in the project.

Context - I have a shared library that I want to user the unstripped version of it, however gradle strips it anyway...

**EDIT**

After some digging, it seems that those tasks are added as part of the binary plugin (the `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` line at the top of the gradle file).

This transform task is added using the [transform API](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/transform-api), which doesn't seems to have a way to unregister/modify existing transform...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's dynamically generated task. Try to add next:

```
android {...}

afterEvaluate { project ->
    project.tasks.transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug {
       onlyIf  {
           println 'Skipping...'
           return false
       }
    }
}

dependencies {...}
```

In Gradle Console you should see:

> Skipping...
>
> :app:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug SKIPPED

Do not forget that ***transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug*** task is only executed, when you use ***assembleDebug*** task (or Shift+F10 combination in Android Studio).